# Bad Block on Nand flahs cell

Tags: computer-science, flash-memory, computer-science-theory

I was researching about Reliability issues on flash memory (Nand). we know that if block is damaged it calls "bad block". But I have some questions that confusing me. looking forward to your help.
Here is my questions:

1.Can we also call that cell as a " bad cell" which include inside that bad blocks?

2.what is the difference between a bad block and bad cell (or damaged cell)?

3.Can bad block occur while program/read or program/write?  (cause it is occur on often erasing block as long as i know)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a flash memory a **cell** is the minimal storage unit, which usually correspond to a single *floating gate transistor*.

It follows naturally that a **bad cell** is a *not working* storage unit.
The term is apparently valid and used, at least in this paper: [Flash Memory Technology](http://smithsonianchips.si.edu/ice/cd/MEMORY97/SEC10.PDF)

> Sometimes audio flash devices may contain some bad cells.

In a *NAND* flash *cells* are organized into **pages** not bytes, in order to achieve better space density.
A **block** is a group of *pages* that can be erased together; as such, *blocks* are just an array of *cells* and a **bad block** is a block containing at least one *bad cell*.

Regarding point three, I honestly can't tell for sure.
Reading, being just a sense, should not really be able to broke a cell.
Erasing, surely can.
According to Wikipedia, programming can be done with [Hot Carrier Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot-carrier_injection#Reliability_impact) that may cause physical damage.

Comment: Thank you @MargaretBloom  for a paper and for a answer. :)